# Users ID numbers messed up - how to change them manually? (urgent)

Tags: joomla-3.x, user

**Background:**
I develop my website on my dev. subdomain and when ready and test and clone dev to the live domain. However at the same time my users may change their password or any other profile data, so before I go live with a new version, I need to save the user profiles with J2XML and load them into the dev website. I test everything on the dev site, but as the live site has to be shut down before  I save the user data, I usually do this after the in-depth testing.

**Issue:**

I got into some trouble. I used to use the J2XML plugin to export and import my Joomla user data when doing site updates. Yesterday I exported my users with a previous version of J2XML and import it with the latest version. Unfortunately the latest version seems to have a bug and does not keep the userIDs even though the setting is on. I would like to avoid going back to an older version of the site and lose user data, so I tried to change manually the id field in the josru_users table, but after that I cannot login with my users:

Warning
You can't access the private section of this site.

What else do I need to do to make sure that my users can log in again?

Thanks a lot, 
W.

Comment: Hi W! I don't get it why you export/import user data on each update? And since you were doing all this, didn't you try the procedure on a testing environment to make sure everything can go smoothly, before doing anything on the production site? Also don't you keep any backups so you can revert back immediately in case something goes wrong? As to what you need to do to have our users being able to login, is to make sure their user accounts/data are as before you did what you did...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your questions. I answered them in the background section of my post.  Yes, I do have backups and in the end I had to revert to an older state of my website, but this means I lost some customer data. I wanted to avoid this, this is why I asked the question.

Comment: Hi - we do not know what kind of user data you will lose -- maybe you could do a migration/sync of data between the 2 states of the records set.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you will have to also update the #__user_usergroup_map table to get the userids you have changed to map correctly back to their original User groups.
I hope you don't have a lot of users.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. In the end I did not dare to continue editing the Joomla DB manually, but decided to revert the whole website to a previous state. This was safe, however I lost some customer data that I had to refill manually. Anyway thanks for your hint.